# mXparser - how to determine the token type of a user defined argument

Tags: java, mxparser

Using the library https://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/playing-with-expression-tokens/

Assume I have the follow functions:

```
val origEl = Expression("revenue - cogs")
origEl.copyOfInitialTokens // this returns an array of `Token`
```

What is the `tokenIdType` here that would indicate we have a user defined argument

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

- http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/playing-with-expression-tokens/
- http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/
- http://mathparser.org/api/
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/parsertokens/package-summary.html
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/parsertokens/Token.html

Generally - in your example you did not define any argument. Parser will find names that are not recognized. It will give you a hint that it look like argument. Take a look on `Token.looksLike` field.

To define user argument follow the tutorial:

- http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/user-defined-arguments/

To get the list of missing user defined arguments take a look on `Expression.getMissingUserDefinedArguments()`, `Expression.getMissingUserDefinedUnits()`, `Expression.getMissingUserDefinedFunctions()`

- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Expression.html#getMissingUserDefinedArguments()
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Expression.html#getMissingUserDefinedUnits()
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Expression.html#getMissingUserDefinedFunctions()

To understand the tokenTypId and tokenId study each mXparser class searching for TYPE_ID value and _ID value, for instance:

- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/parsertokens/BinaryRelation.html
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/parsertokens/BinaryRelation.html#TYPE_ID
- http://mathparser.org/api/org/mariuszgromada/math/mxparser/Argument.html#TYPE_ID
- ...

Best regards

Comment: Thank you Leroy this is exactly what I am looking for, especially the how to interpret the tokenTypId